# Deploy specific folder to drop

Tags: tfs, msbuild

We have a fairly heterogenous build environment, but our main entry point is MSBuild. We have the build set up so that all the binary artifacts end up in a single folder, `Output`. (Or rather in subfoders in the single folder...)

Is there an easy way to mark the `Output` folder for deployment and have the build agent deploy it to a drop location? (We already have a drop location working, but currently our setup only deploys build logs.)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you want to manage the artifact of TFS Build Output.

If you are using the new build system vNext build, you can add task [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts). In task Copy and Publish Build Artifacts, there is an item called "Content", Contents specify minimatch pattern filters (one on each line) that you want to apply to the list of files to be copied. You can also specify Artifact Type to Server or Local. [Manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/)

If you are using old build system XAML build, you can  change Output Location setting in build definition. Output Location setting can be set to the values SingleFolder, PerProject, AsConfigured. You may check blog below for more information: http://blogs.objectsharp.com/post/2014/08/22/Separate-TFS-Build-Server-Output-into-Different-Folders.aspx